# External javascript files stop working after first page change reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've imported javascript files in public-> index.html, but whenever I change the page it stops working.
And it comes back as soon as i reload the same page.

Can anyone help me out with this how should I call external javascript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of your comment

> I've converted html theme to react. In index.html I've imported
>   carousel js [...] When I load the website for first time it works
>   properly but when go to some other page and then come back to the home
>   page carousel stops working.

It sounds like you use an older, non-react script. **DON'T DO THIS!**

You are not allowed to change the DOM if you use React. *Every* change must go through react to work.

The reason it won't work on the second viewing is that you don't look at the same HTML elements, but freshly rendered ones.

The first render, where you had the carousel working was completely deleted when you viewed another page. And then, when you came back, React rendered the first page again. But you never re-started the carousel, so of course it doesn't work.

The solution is to use a carousel library built for React. I'm sure there are hundreds of them.

Answer (score 0):

Once a script file is loaded, it stays available, so it sounds like you have some kind of logic error in your code.

Comment: I've converted html theme to react. In index.html I've imported carousel js file using the script tag which is in body tag. When I load the website for first time it works properly but when go to some other page and then come back to the home page carousel stops working. How to resolve this Issue?

Comment: and i get this in the console `[...effects] has been deprecated in favor of all([...effects]), please update your code`